# Get hour with highest row count

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Consider a table entitled 'Calls', that among other things, contains the following columns:

```
  CalledNumber | CallBegin
-----------------------------------
004401151234567|10/08/2013 09:06:53
004303111238493|15/09/2013 14:56:29
```

and so on...

How would one go about picking out the hour that, averaged over a date range, holds the highest number of rows? The goal is to find the 'Busy Hour' for each quarter in a year. SQL really isn't my forte here, and I'm looking at manipulating up to a 9.6Million rows at times, although, execution time isn't a key problem.

Comment: Group by the hour part of the date (and year, month, day ofc.), count() calledNumbers, and sort accordingly.

Comment: Is `CallBegin` stored as a date?  That's not the standard format for SQL dates, so I wanted to clarify.

Comment: @DavidStarkey it in fact is stored as a DateTime, apparently the long day took it's toll my old brain...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`DATEPART`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT
    DATEPART(hour, CallBegin), COUNT(*) as NumberOfCalls
FROM
    Test
WHERE
    CallBegin BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-12-31'
GROUP BY
    DATEPART(hour, CallBegin)
ORDER BY
    NumberOfCalls DESC
```

Working [**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1d08b/2)

Comment: Ah this is fantastic. Sorry for my lack of SQL knowledge, and thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DATEPART()` and `CONVERT()`, I'm assuming CallBegin is not stored as datetime:

```
SELECT  YEAR(CONVERT(DATETIME,CallBegin,103))'Year'
      , DATEPART(quarter,CONVERT(DATETIME,CallBegin,103))'Quarter'
      , DATEPART(hour,CONVERT(DATETIME,CallBegin,103))'Hour'
      , COUNT(*)
FROM Calls
GROUP BY YEAR(CONVERT(DATETIME,CallBegin,103))
       , DATEPART(quarter,CONVERT(DATETIME,CallBegin,103))
       , DATEPART(hour,CONVERT(DATETIME,CallBegin,103))
```

If you want to span years just eliminate the year portion:

```
SELECT  DATEPART(quarter,CONVERT(DATETIME,CallBegin,103))'Quarter'
      , DATEPART(hour,CONVERT(DATETIME,CallBegin,103))'Hour'
      , COUNT(*)
FROM Calls
GROUP BY DATEPART(quarter,CONVERT(DATETIME,CallBegin,103))
       , DATEPART(hour,CONVERT(DATETIME,CallBegin,103))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx). I.e.,

```
SELECT  DATEPART(hh, CallBegin) ,
    COUNT(1) as callCount
FROM Calls
GROUP BY DATEPART(hh, CallBegin)
ORDER BY callCount DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `datePart`, try using `DateAdd()` and `DateDiff()`

```
  Select top 1 DateAdd(hour, DateDiff(hour, 0, CallBegin), 0)
  From Calls
  Group By DateAdd(hour, DateDiff(hour, 0, CallBegin), 0) 
  Order By Count(*) Desc
```

This will perform better because it is purely arithmetic, i.e., there is no parsing of textual representations of dates and/or dateTimes.

Add the count to see how many occurred during that hour

```
  Select top 1 DateAdd(hour, DateDiff(hour, 0, CallBegin), 0), Count(*)
  From Calls
  Group By DateAdd(hour, DateDiff(hour, 0, CallBegin), 0) 
  Order By Count(*) Desc
```